# EF Core / SQL Server same foreign keys with one Cascade and one SetNull

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, ef-core-3.1

I have a `Profiles` table that I want to add contact requests. Each profile has multiple `RequestsSent` and multiple `RequestsReceived`.

I want to achieve a behavior that when a profile is deleted, `OnDelete` all requests that have been sent from (`FromId`, `From`) the deleted profile are get to `Cascade` and all requests that have been sent to (`ToId`, `To`) are get to `SetNull`.

```cs
public class Profile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ProfileId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("From")]
    public virtual ICollection<Requests> RequestsSent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Requests> RequestsReceived { get; set; }
}
```

with the requests model:

```cs
public class Requests
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long RequestId { get; set; }

    public long FromId { get; set; }
    public Profile From { get; set; }

    // Nullable FK
    public long? ToId { get; set; }
    public virtual Profile To { get; set; }
}
```

and inside DB context `OnModelCreating`:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>()
    .HasMany(p => p.RequestsReceived)
    .WithOne(p => p.To)
    .IsRequired(false)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

Having `SetNull` inside `OnModelCreating` results in database error when trying to apply the migration:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint `FK_BusinessContactRequests_BusinessProfiles_ToId` on table `BusinessContactRequests` may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>       Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I'm changing `SetNull` to `NoAction` and it migrates to to the database.

Now, having the following data:

[image: Requests Table Data]

When I try to delete the profile with `ProfileId:21`, I get the following SQL Error:

> Error Source: .Net SqICIient Data Provider.
>
> Error Message: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>
> `FK_Request_Profiles_ToId` The conflict occurred in database `MyDB`, table `dbo.Requests`, column `Told` The statement has been terminated.
>
> Correct the errors and attempt to delete the row again or press ESC to cancel the change(s).

If I use SSMS and change `FK_Request_Profiles_ToId` *Table Designer* > *Enforce Foreign Key Constraints* to **"No"** it partially works but it leaves the `ToId` with the old one:

[image: After delete result]

**Question:**

How can I have the FK `ToId` with `OnDelete` `SetNull` to work and if this is not possible, how can I set *Enforce Foreign Key Constraints* to **"No"** through code using EF Core?

**UPDATE**

My solution for now is to remove all `modelBuilder` code inside `OnModelCreating` and have `InverseProperty("To")` on `RequestsReceived` instead of `[InverseProperty("From")]` to `RequestsSent`. That also results in SQL Server error when trying to delete a profile, but it does not if I manually set all `ToId` to `NULL` before the deletion.